# Headers not sending

Tags: php, sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNcit.png)   Headers are not being sent - I believe, not sure what the problem is have tried to remove them for tests but no luck, still not working. Form just keeps reloading, not processing any data. Connection details are out obviously for the sake of this post.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))


     if(isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];



        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT firstname, Clientid, password FROM Client WHERE email=?");

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $result_forename, $result_id, $result_password);
        while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){

                if(password_verify($password, $result_password))
          {
            // Store Session Data
             // $_SESSION['email']= $email;  // Initializing Session with value of PHP Variable


              //Create cookie, with forename value
              //$cookie_name = "name";
              //$cookie_value = $result_forename;
              //setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day





        //admin status check
        if($result_id >= 1){


          header('Location: appointment.php'); exit();

          echo "Welcome " . $result_forename;
        }
        else {

          echo"Error, please register first before attempting to login";




        }

          }
          }



    }
    ?>
```

Here's the appointment page that it is trying to redirect to

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){


     $staffid=$_POST['Staffid'];
     $clientid=$_POST['Clientid'];
     $urgency=$_POST['Urgency'];
     $concern=$_POST['Concern'];
     $aptdate=$_POST['Apt_date'];
     $apttime=$_POST['Apt_time'];
     $aptduration=$_POST['Apt_duration'];
     $location=$_POST['Location'];

     //prepared statement
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO Appointment (Staffid, Clientid, Urgency,Concern,Apt_date,Apt_time,Apt_duration,Location ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    //dealing with the parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iissiiis", $staffid, $clientid, $urgency,$concern, $aptdate, $apttime, $aptduration, $location);
            if ($stmt->execute()) { 
               echo"Appointment has been booked";
            } else {
               echo"Appointment hasn't been booked";
            }



}
?>
```

Comment: Your php open tag must be `<?php` instead of just `<?`.

Comment: just an error copying the code over as added that bit in, problem is still there, mainly the login page im needing the advice on, if it is the headers that are the error as I suspect then how do I go about sorting it?

Comment: Have you session_start() in your login page?

Comment: You can't output anything before a header call. It will cause an error.

Comment: Header redirect must be followed right after by exit(); so no other codes will be executed after redirect.

Comment: Adding in the exit(); hasn't changed anything, the form just reloads, the echo statements aren't displaying either, nevermind the redirect header

Comment: Just inside your while loop can you do `die("$result_forename, $result_id, $result_password");` - what's the output?

Comment: prints the variable values, on screen underneath the form